# formula for the Average of the change in a column of numbers from row to row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, formula, average

Does anyone know a formula for the Average of the change in a column of numbers from row to row in pandas?

what about greatest increase and decrease between rows?

need to answer the following questions from an csv file with pandas

Average change in revenue:
greatest change:
greatest decrease:

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What's stopping you from answering the questions, OP?

Comment: yeah. its a small part of a larger assignment, cant figure out what kind of formula i should be using to calculate the average of the change in each row and the greatest increase/decrease in each row

Comment: well i cant figure out how to formulate the for loop. im a new student so this is a bit frustrating

Answer (score 1):

First, create a column with shifted values from 'observed_column' (or whatever name you have on your dataset):

```
df['shifted_column'] = df['observed_column'].shift(1)
```

Second, create a column with the difference between current value ('observed_column') and last line value ('shifted_column'):

```
df['difference'] = df['observed_column'] - df['shifted_column']
```

Third, get absolute values to measure change (doesn't seem necessary to your problem, but just in case):

```
df['difference'] = df['difference'].abs()
```

Fourth, compute the statistics:

```
average = df['difference'].mean()
maximum = df['difference'].max()
minimum = df['difference'].min()
```

Comment: ahhhhh abs! and shift! thanks so much will try when i get back to workstation

Comment: See also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html